# RichFaces a4j actionParam inside of jsFunction

Tags: jsf, richfaces, ajax4jsf

I have a jsFunction which has some nested actionParams and a defined action. I need to know in which order will those actions be performed (injecting param 1, param 2 and doing the action) - will it inject params before invoking the function, will it be done asynchronously?

```
<a4j:jsFunction name="fun" action="#{bean.doSomething}">
    <a4j:actionparam name="param1" assignTo="#{bean2.param1}"/>
    <a4j:actionparam name="param2" assignTo="#{bean2.param2}"/>
</a4j:jsFunction>
```

Comment: You could just fire debug...

Answer (score 0):

As per JSF lifecycle, update models values comes before invoke application phase. So Function will be called in invoke application phase. So actionParams are assigned first (update model
Values )and then the action method (invoke application )is

A4j: jsfunction is similar to a4j:commandbutton

https://docs.jboss.org/richfaces/latest_3_3_X/en/devguide/html/a4j_jsFunction.html

http://balusc.omnifaces.org/2006/09/debug-jsf-lifecycle.html?m=1